# What is wrong with my question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

I have asked a math question on Mathematics StackExchange: [How many ways to split n elements in k groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675787/how-many-ways-to-split-n-elements-in-k-groups) Then I asked on StackOverflow that [How to use C++ to count how many ways to split n elements in k groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770963/how-to-use-c-to-count-how-many-ways-to-split-n-elements-in-k-groups)

The first question I got several cool answers. They explained me the Math concepts. The second one I want to know how to make the algorithm into code. However, instead of getting the solutions, I got down votes.

One has commended that the result can be found on Wikipedia, but he did not give me a link or keyword to that.

Another one says my second question is a possible duplicate of my first one...

If people just keep downvoting my questions, I will never even get the ability to upvote any good answers. What is wrong with my question? What I am supposed to ask in StackOverflow?

Comment: I think that you haven't really shown any effort.  A better approach would have been to say, "I started coding these ideas ..." but when I got to this part ... I get this error / am stuck".

Comment: You should have post what have you tried. No one is going to write the code for you. IMO that is the reason for downvotes.

Comment: One of the mistake, based from your post, is to ask for full code. It can be seen as "not showing effort to research". By the way, I've commented about the link on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look at you [math question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/675787), you have showed some effort by referring other question with an example.

> For example, in a more specific question How many ways to split 5
>   number in 2 groups?, *we got the answer 15 from Jared, which is the sum
>   of 5 ways to split in group size 1 and 4, and 10 ways to to split in
>   group size 2 and 3.*

Whereas in this [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21770963/1671639) you haven't even quoted the algorithm that you've framed.

> I have asked How many ways to split n elements in k groups on
>   Mathematics StackExchange. The answers are very intuitive, but I would
>   also like to know how to get the answer by code.

At least you should have tried to frame [Pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) to show that you have well understood the concept.

At last you haven't read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Don't wrong about your downvotes, take sometime and try it yourself and still if you don't get it then update that closed question.

Hope you can understand.

Answer (score 3):

Your down-voted question is a "do you haz teh codes" question:

- no research effort (code or topic)
- no attempted code
- "do my work for me" tone